# mvc Remove url page name from response redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url

I have read a lot of post telling how to remove `Controller` an `Action` from Url

My case is simplest but do not haw to do it.

When Start, it execute `Home` Controller for default. Depending Active Directory conditions I have to redirect to certain standard HTML. It could be

```
Response.Redirect("Page1.html");
Response.Redirect("Page2.html");
Response.Redirect("Page3.html");
```

It will show

```
 Localhost:4000/Page1.html or
 Localhost:4000/Page2.html or
 Localhost:4000/Page3.html
```

What i need is to show only

> Localhost:4000

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may want to write a specific action like this

so first lets say your route config is intact and default rouute is being used then in home controller change its index like ths

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
       if(Your condition)
    {
      return new FilePathResult($"~/Views/Page1.html.html", "text/html");
    }  
      if(Your condition2)
    {
      return new FilePathResult($"~/Views/Page2.html", "text/html");
    }  
        if(Your condition3)
    {
      return new FilePathResult($"~/Views/Page3.html", "text/html");
    }    
}
```

Comment: add required naespace man cctrl+. and let the intelesence do its work

Comment: RAHUL, i know that, i was traying to say I was not familiar with that method... that all.. thanks.